# Loading gif image visible while the execution process runs

Tags: c#

I am using window app and C#.. i have a picture which is invisible at the start of the app.. when some button is clicked, the picture box has to be shown..

i use this coding but the picture box is not visible

```
 private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbproject.Text == "---Select---")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Project Name");
                return;             
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                pictureBox1.BringToFront();
                pictureBox1.Show();

                FillReport();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: this code is not working and gif image doesnot get shown at all....please help me to find the answer

Comment: You never need `BringToFront` or `Show` on a control. Make sure the control is visible in the designer (and nothing is on top of it). Then this should work.

Comment: in back there is a gridview thats the reason  i brought the picturebox     in front i tried all the possibilities but image is not showing up ..while in the execution

Comment: Give the GUI a break to repaint itself. To do so add this line after the pictureBox1.Show();``:  `Application.DoEvents();`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Sleep` - that blocks the thread, which means no windows messages get processed, and your form won't get repainted.

Instead, you could use a `Timer` to hide the image after 5 seconds.

Add a timer to your form, and change your code to be something like this:

```
pictureBox1.Visible = true;    
FillReport();
timer1.Interval = 5000;
timer1.Start();
```

And in the timer event:

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

Now your image should be visible for 5 seconds.

However, the form will still not repaint while `FillReport` is executing. If you need the image to be visible at that point, I suggest using a `BackgroundWorker` to execute `FillReport` so that it doesn't block the UI thread. Then you can hide the image in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

Comment: now please tell how can i work with the load image so that my image is shown when the Fillreport() function gets executed....

Comment: please explain me the backgroundwoker to execute so that it doesnot block the thread ?

Comment: No - try to figure it out yourself, and ask a new question if you can't.